# Parsing Error in Powershell: Missing Terminator "

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been racking my brain on this one and can't seem to figure it out. I don't see any extra quotes anywhere. Am I running into an issue with parsing the quotes?

```
The string starting:
At C:\scripts\365-export.ps1:288 char
:51
+ $execute = read-host -Prompt "Are you Sure?: (y/n) <<<< "
is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\scripts\365-export.ps1:297 char
:9
+ MainMenu <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (
if ($execute ...u}
}
MainMenu:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Here are lines 288 through 297

```
$execute = read-host -Prompt "Are you Sure?: (y/n)"
if ($execute -ieq y) {New-MailboxSearch $searchname $endD $estimate $excludedupes $force $iph  $recipient $keyword $sender $sourcebox $startD $statusmail $targetbox
} else {SConfMenu}


#END OF COMMAND EXECUTION
} else {
MainMenu}
}
MainMenu
```

I'm not sure if this will help but I've placed the script in pastebin here:
http://pastebin.ca/2532441

Any help is appreciated.

After adding the recommended quotes at ($execute -ieq "y"), I'm receiving this error now...

```
The string starting:
At C:\scripts\365-export.ps1:289 char
:21
+ if ($execute -ieq "y <<<< ") {New-MailboxSearch $searchname $endD $estimate $
excludedupes $force $iph  $recipient $keyword $sender $sourcebox $startD $statu
smail $targetbox
is missing the terminator: ".
```

Comment: Perhaps try `($execute -ieq "y")`?

Answer (score 1):

missing " @ ($execute -ieq y)
if ($execute -ieq **"**y***"*)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found earlier in the code.

There was a problem with a variable that needed to be quoted with single quotes instead of double quotes.